# Converting a SQL query that uses views to directly hit the tables

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

Is there an easy / automated way to convert a query that is written using views to hit the tables under the view directly?

We have a database that has a ton of very simple views that hit views that hit views and the performance is exactly what you would expect. The query plans are gigantic. The problem I have with manually converting is that since the tables are 3+ views deep it's very time consuming to try to determine the base tables.

Comment: I fear "View Dependencies" is going to be your friend very shortly...

Answer (score 0):

A *STATIC* cursor that will iterate through:

```
select T2.name + '.' + T1.name [name], OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) [definition]
from sys.views T1
    inner join sys.schemas T2 ON T1.schema_id = T2.schema_id
```

doing optionall filtering, reconfiguring and finally injecting the new definition into `exec sp_executesql` will do well here.